Firebase Google Authentication not working in Telegram's in-app browser (React)
I have a React app using Firebase for authentication. The app currently requires Google login. Here's the issue I'm facing:
On both my Mac and iPhone, when I open the app in regular browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc.), Google login works perfectly.
However, when I open the app via Telegram's in-app browser on my iPhone and press "Login with Google," the following happens:
The Google authentication popup opens.
I select my Google account, input my password, and submit.
The authentication tab closes, but I am not logged in to the React app.
For some reason, the login flow works everywhere except in Telegram's in-app browser.
Here's my relevant code:
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log("RESULT: ", result);
            const u = result.user;
            // Setup real-time listener after login
            setupUserListener(u.uid);
            alert(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error during sign-in:', error);
        });
};

I also tried using signInWithRedirect, but it didn't work in Telegram's in-app browser either. I ran this code to see if the user would persist but I'm getting "null":
useEffect(() => {
        getRedirectResult(auth)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("R: ", result)
            })
    }, []);

